# Adding a parent class between models.Model and my Model classes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have different apps that pertain to different functionalities, but typically they all follow more or less the same patterns. In order to have easy (and flexible) access to the data I need in my templates, I need to implement some methods in my Models. For instance, these methods would be needed in a few different apps in order to populate a list view that contains only a small subset of all the fields of the model:

```
class Produit(models.Model):
    # fields to present the summary
    summary_table_headers = ["id","no_prod","descfr","descang", ...]

    @classmethod
    def get_list_summary_headers(cls):
        """ returns the table headers so the template can easily populate <th>"""
        # return [h for h in cls.summary_table_headers]
        return [(h, cls._meta.get_field(h).verbose_name) for h in cls.summary_table_headers]
```

Then I have bunch of different apps, but all needs to present a summary list view of sorts. Things are still very much in development, so I wanted to be able change what is to be part of the summary in ONE place (e.g. the models). Then the template just iterates and renders everything that's handed to it. If I need to add/remove/change the fields to be part of the summary, I only need to edit the summary_table_headers.

Therefore I wanted to user a parent class, define all those `get_....()` methods in that base class to keep things DRY. However if I do:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    summary_table_headers = []
    # define above methods in this base class

class Products(MyModel)
    # simple model definition, without the methods I moved to the MyModel
```

Then I get:

```
OperationalError at /products/

no such table: products_mymodel
```

So I am guessing that because of the way Django manages the backend, I cannot simply put a intermediate class between models.Model & my database definition.

Is there an easy fix to make that happen? Failing that, any smart idea to avoid copying all those methods all over my apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Abstract Base Classes for that.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    summary_table_headers = []
    # define above methods in this base class
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: Ah. I did skip the docs's TOC but apparently AbstractBaseClass didn't ring a bell. THanks.

Comment: No problem! Now it does